# Drive Space Allocation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

According to the image in step 4 of here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop, I need to specify how much space I should allocate for Ubuntu. What does this mean? Is it referring to the space allocated for the OS itself, or programs included? I am planning to install Ubuntu on an SSD. I will also be installing my programs onto it. Then I have another HDD where my files will go. So how should I set up the dragger in that step to go with my situation?
Also, this is an installation into a new build, so I have no previous OS installed, nor do I plan to dual-boost.

**EDIT:**

So based on what @heynnema told me and some other research I've done, this is what I understand I should do:

1. Select the "Something else" installation type.
2. Then I'll be taken to a screen similar to this: http://blog.sudobits.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/partition-manager.png but with just /dev/sda. And I understand that this is the SSD. So then I should click it and then "New Partition Table", thus providing "free space" for a total of about 120000 MB (120GB SSD).
3. Then I should click "free space", and then click "Add". From there I should enter the max amount available, as shown in the previous screen next to "free space". And the "Type for the new partition" is "Logical", the "Location for the new partition" is "Beginning of this space", the option chosen for "Use as" is "Ext4 journaling file system", and the "Mount point" is "/". With those, I should click OK.
4. Now I should be back to the screen I was when I first pressed "Something else" and continued. Then I'm not too sure at all, but I understand that I should change the dropdown for "Device for boot loader installation" to "/dev/sdb ...", which is the HDD. I'm not sure if I have to do this, or if I shouldn't touch that at all, leaving it at "/dev/sda ...", the SSD, and "/dev/sdb" should've been in the device list from the start. From there I should click "/dev/sdb" in the device list, again click "New Partition Table...", then the newly generated "free space", and "Add".
5. In the screen that appears from pressing "Add", I should enter 20000 MB (16 GB, which is my total RAM,  multiplied by 1.25, and of course converted to MB) for the "Size", "Primary" for the "Type for the new partition", "Beginning of this space" again for the "Location for the new partition", and "swap area" as the "Use as" dropdown option. Then I should click OK.
6. Next I should again click free space under "/dev/sbd", and then "Add". Then I should enter the maximum size remaining on the HDD for the "Size" (which will be the amount shown in "free space" originally minus 20000 MB for the swap area). And then "Primary" for "Type for the new partition" (not positive if it should be Primary or Logical here), "Beginning of this space" for "Location for the new partition", "Ext4 journaling file system" for "Use as", and "/home" for "Mount point". Then Click OK, and "Install Now" on the following screen.

What I'm not too sure about is if the SSD *will* be sda and the HDD sdb. Is there a chance they'll be switched, and how will I know which one is which if so? Also, I've seen suggestions to add partitions for "/boot", "/tmp", and "/var". Is that something I should do, and how and where can I fit that into the steps above? And my understanding is that doing this makes it so the OS and all my programs/apps are installed on the SSD as to utilize the speed that is offered. And then all my documents, images, videos, files, etc. are on the HDD. Am I right in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how big the SSD and the HDD is. I'll assume that the SSD is smallish... 240GB or smaller.

The short answer...

I'd install root (/) on the SSD. Use the whole thing, unless you think that you'll be installing another OS at a later date.

I'd put /home and /swap on the HDD. Make swap 1-1.5 RAM size.

Please ask if you have further questions. Cheers, Al

edit:

note... please research all of my answers such that you'll be 100% comfortable and correct with the outcome :-)

step 3: I'm not 100% sure if it should be `primary` or `logical`.

step 4: Leave the boot loader on sda.

step 5: Leave your swap at 1XRAM, so 16GB.

Q: What I'm not too sure about is if the SSD will be sda and the HDD sdb. Is there a chance they'll be switched, and how will I know which one is which if so? `you'll know by the size of the disks`.

Q: Also, I've seen suggestions to add partitions for "/boot", "/tmp", and "/var". Is that something I should do, and how and where can I fit that into the steps above? `don't bother`.

Q: And my understanding is that doing this makes it so the OS and all my programs/apps are installed on the SSD as to utilize the speed that is offered. `programs/apps will end up on root (/) your sda drive`.

Q: And then all my documents, images, videos, files, etc. are on the HDD. Am I right in this? `yes`.

Good luck! Let us know how it went, and if you had to adjust the steps along the way! Cheers, Al

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not too familiar with all the directories. My SSD is 120GB and my HDD is 1TB. I also noticed that there is an alternative, in step 3, to "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu". Should I still choose "Something else"?

Comment: root (/) is where your system files and your applications go. /home is where your personal files go. /swap is used by the system if you're running low on memory. Because I'm spreading them out over two disks, you'll have to use `Something else`, and then specify root to take up all of the SSD (sda), /swap to take up 1-1.5 RAM size on the HDD (sdb) with the remainder going to /home (sdb).

Comment: So I can't have programs installed on the SSD? And 1-1.5 _RAM_ on the HDD?

Comment: Yes programs/applications would normally be on the root drive, SSD in your case. The /swap partition on the HDD would be size such that the formula for its size is take the size of your physical memory, multiply it by 1-1.5, and then make the swap partition that big... ie: 8GB RAM, then 8GB swap partition. Cheers, Al

Comment: I edited my original post to add in my understanding of the steps I must take to accomplish my goal, based on the information you gave and other information I have gathered elsewhere. Does everything look good, and can you help clarify some of the questions I added into that?

Comment: I'll edit my answer, above, to detail my responses to your questions. The last question, regarding /boot, /tmp, /var, is don't worry about them. Every time that I've seen somebody manually set these up, they always undersize them, and it causes trouble later when they fill up. When we're all done, you can vote/accept my answer, if you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: So not adding /boot, /temp, and /var isn't harmful at all?

Comment: I'm not 1000% sure if (especially if you choose logical partition for sda) that the installer will/won't take care of that for you. Ask the question and see if other experts can chime in on the smaller details. I just worried about the big ones :-)

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I'll look more into that with primary/logical, and boot, temp, and var. But you really helped out a lot. I barely knew a thing about the Ubuntu file layout beforehand but now I'm fairly comfortable with it and will be able to do what I wanted to (with that little bit more research of course). So thank you very much! Definitely voting and accepting this answer! :)
*Ah, looks like I can't vote yet! Darn! I'd give you a bounty if I could.